# Macbook Pro 16" keeps shutting down

Tags: macbook-pro

So out of nowhere, my Macbook pro 16" laptop from work keeps shutting down as soon as I try to start it. The fan would spin for a second and the Apple logo would appear, and then things would turn off. None of this happens if the power is not connected. I have tried resetting SMC and NVRAM or PRAM, none seems to be working. What could be the issue?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As this is not your personal computer, it belongs to your employer, you should consult with your companies tech support. Additionally, as the MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) first came out in November 2019 and its warranty may be getting close to running out if it was purchased then, contacting Apple Support in any case is what should be done.

Comment: @user3439894 thanks, I only got my hands on this about 2 months ago, so it's still well under warranty!

Comment: Before it restarts, does it briefly come up with some text with a power symbol behind the text? If so, this indicates its having a kernel panic. You can check if you have kernel panics in the Console.app. In the sidebar, go to ‘/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports’ and you should see a list of reports and look for kernel panics. This might help you identify if it’s kernel panicking and by what. You should also do an apple diagnostics test and boot in Safe Mode

Comment: @AVelj I can't start the machine at all

Comment: You can try boot in safe mode and/or do an Apple diagnostics test. But it sounds like something has failed in the hardware. It’s not really your responsibility to fix it but rather your business’ tech support, which will be still under warranty if it’s less than a year old